# Ensuring Node.js v20 compatibility in a .NET workflow

Tags: node.js, .net, github-actions

I want to ensure a .NET project using GitHub Actions uses Node.js v20, but it doesn't explicitly specify any Node.js version anywhere. I found [GitHub blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/) about transitioning from Node.js 16 to Node.js 20.

Currently, only the `actions/checkout@v3` action is defined in all five workflow YAML files within the `.github` folder. Does `actions/checkout@v3` implicitly install Node.js v16? I'm unsure whether I need to explicitly define `node-version: 20` in the action configuration to use Node.js v20. If I want to use Node.js v20 version, would `actions/checkout@v4` be enough, or do I need to explicitly state that?

```
- name: Setup .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
  with:
    dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    node-version: 20
```

If I want to explicitly mention this, do I need to put this in every YAML file?

I updated the `actions/checkout` version from v3 to v4, and attempted to specify Node.js v20 in the `setup-dotnet` action:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v4

- name: Setup .NET
  uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
  with:
    dotnet-version: 8.0.x
    node-version: 20
```

I anticipated that these changes would ensure the workflow uses Node.js v20 as instructed in the GitHub Actions transition documentation.

Since I haven't tested the workflow yet, I'm uncertain whether the specified Node.js version is applied correctly.

Comment: `actions/checkout` [v4](https://github.com/actions/checkout/releases/tag/v4.0.0) and `/setup-dotnet` [v4](https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/releases/tag/v4.0.0) both use Node 20. Neither has a defined input that lets you _configure_ that. Read their `action.yml` which tell you both of these things.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a beginner and I am contributing to open source. I appreciate your guidance. Regarding your reply, does the absence of an action.yml file mean it wasn't using Node.js version? In the other five YAML files, Node is not explicitly defined anywhere. This is why I'm getting confused.

Comment: What absence of `action.yml`? They both (like every action must) have that file.

Comment: I've rechecked, and I'm confident that the repositories  do not include an action.yml file. My examination of the repository contents reveals only the following YAML files:

- codeql-analysis.yml (2,801 bytes)
- codeql-required-workaround.yml (702 bytes)
- create-release.yml (2,572 bytes)
- dotnet-required-workaround.yml (618 bytes)
- dotnet.yml (1,289 bytes)

There doesn't appear to be an action.yml file in these repositories.

Comment: https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/main/action.yml, https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/blob/main/action.yml. Also note e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action.

Answer (score 0):

There's literally an `action.yml` file in the latest PR merged to `actions/setup-dotnet` that transitioned the action to node 20: https://github.com/actions/setup-dotnet/pull/484/files#diff-1243c5424efaaa19bd8e813c5e6f6da46316e63761421b3e5f5c8ced9a36e6b6

Just update to use @v4 of the action and it will support node 20 out of the box.